# Installing list of packages - How can i know where it failed

Tags: ansible

I want to check if a list of packages installed on linux. I run Ansible with --check to make a dry run.

```
- name: Install Basic Packages specific version
      yum:
        name={{ item }}
        state=present
      with_items:
       -  long
       -  packages
       -  list
       -  ...
```

When it found something to change, it give the all list of packages + the line:

```
XXX : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

How can I get, in dry run,  the specific package that should be changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run with more verbosity `-vv` and each task for each item will be displayed with it's changed status.

But the `yum` module treat a `with_items` loop in 1 run, so you have to look at the returned output of the task to see if it displays the specific package that will change.

Comment: The -vv give more information like: {"changed": true, "changes": {"installed": ["vim"]}

Answer (score 2):

Register the `yum` task result and add a debug task (with an option to run it only with `--check`):

```
- name: Install Basic Packages specific version
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
   - long
   - packages
   - list
   - ...
  register: yum_task

- debug:
    var: yum_task.results[0].changes.installed
  when: ansible_check_mode and yum_task.results[0].changed
```

Comment: Where can I find good documentation about the structure of the variables I can access during ansible run like xx.results[0].changes.installed above?                    I saw that this variable exist when I'm dry run, How can I know how this variable called when I not in dry run?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the latter part of your comment. I guess there is no documentation. Use `debug` module to display the values and customise the code accordingly.